# Reassigning bundle values to individual products SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

My dataset tracks customer orders. Customers can buy a bundle, and are then charged one bundle_price:

[image]

Customer 1 bought bundle A, for a bundle_price of 200. The different products within the bundle are also listed with its original list_price. I want to reassign this bundle_price to each individual product, so that I can exclude bundles from my dataset. I want to add two columns: List_Ratio and Ratio_Bundle_Price. The data should look like this:

[image]

I am thinking to use a case statement with a window function, but not sure how to exactly execute this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: dont post the table data as images , post as script or create a fiddle , then SO can reproduce the issue you facing and sort it out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       list_price / SUM(list_price) OVER (PARTITION BY customer)
         AS list_ratio,
       ROUND(
         list_price
         * SUM(discounted_price) OVER (PARTITION BY customer)
         / SUM(list_price) OVER (PARTITION BY customer),
         2
       ) AS ratio_bundle_price
FROM   table_name t
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (customer, product_number, bundle_product, list_price, discounted_price) AS
  SELECT 1, 'A', 'Y',   0, 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'B', 'N', 180,   0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'C', 'N',  20,   0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'D', 'N',  70,   0 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| CUSTOMER | PRODUCT_NUMBER | BUNDLE_PRODUCT | LIST_PRICE | DISCOUNTED_PRICE | LIST_RATIO | RATIO_BUNDLE_PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Y | 0 | 200 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | D | N | 70 | 0 | .2592592592592592592592592592592592592593 | 51.85 |
| 1 | C | N | 20 | 0 | .0740740740740740740740740740740740740741 | 14.81 |
| 1 | B | N | 180 | 0 | .6666666666666666666666666666666666666667 | 133.33 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xygmsGwf)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This works if a customer has multiple products,  but if they have only 1 product with both a list_price and discounted_price the list_ratio returns a null. How to account for this?

Comment: @Es-Dot Please provide a [MRE] that replicates the problem because when I try [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1c-q5a3u) it does not give a `NULL` value.